# Create a dropdown using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm a new developer and still learning and i would appreciate a bit help in here coz I'm already insane.
I have this code, trying to make a dropdown with some options but i can't make it work. In inspector mode it says Uncaught ReferenceError, jQuery not defined it doesn't do the dropdown.

```html
<div class="container">
        <nav class="fixed-top nav-menu nav d-lg block justify-content-end">
            <!--<div class="right">-->
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        "Nome Utilizador"
                    </li>
                    <li class="drop-down"><a href="#">Action</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li class="dropdown-item">
                        exemplo
                        </li>   
                    </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            <!--</div>-->
        </nav>
        
</div>


  
  
  <script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="vendor/counterup/counterup.min.js"></script> 
  <script src="vendor/owl.carousel/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
  <script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script src="vendor/jquery.easing/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
  <script src="vendor/php-email-form/validate.js"></script>
  <script src="vendor/waypoints/jquery.waypoints.min.js"></script> 
  <script src="vendor/venobox/venobox.min.js"></script>
  
  <script src="vendor/isotope-layout/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>
  <script src="vendor/aos/aos.js"></script>
```

This is the Main.js code

```js
/**
* Template Name: OnePage - v2.2.2
* Template URL: https://bootstrapmade.com/onepage-multipurpose-bootstrap-template/
* Author: BootstrapMade.com
* License: https://bootstrapmade.com/license/
*/
!(function($) {
  "use strict";

  // Preloader
  $(window).on('load', function() {
    if ($('#preloader').length) {
      $('#preloader').delay(100).fadeOut('slow', function() {
        $(this).remove();
      });
    }
  });

  // Smooth scroll for the navigation menu and links with .scrollto classes
  var scrolltoOffset = $('#header').outerHeight() - 2;
  $(document).on('click', '.nav-menu a, .mobile-nav a, .scrollto', function(e) {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      if (target.length) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var scrollto = target.offset().top - scrolltoOffset;

        if ($(this).attr("href") == '#header') {
          scrollto = 0;
        }

        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: scrollto
        }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');

        if ($(this).parents('.nav-menu, .mobile-nav').length) {
          $('.nav-menu .active, .mobile-nav .active').removeClass('active');
          $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');
        }

        if ($('body').hasClass('mobile-nav-active')) {
          $('body').removeClass('mobile-nav-active');
          $('.mobile-nav-toggle i').toggleClass('icofont-navigation-menu icofont-close');
          $('.mobile-nav-overly').fadeOut();
        }
        return false;
      }
    }
  });

  // Activate smooth scroll on page load with hash links in the url
  $(document).ready(function() {
    if (window.location.hash) {
      var initial_nav = window.location.hash;
      if ($(initial_nav).length) {
        var scrollto = $(initial_nav).offset().top - scrolltoOffset;
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: scrollto
        }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');
      }
    }
  });

  // Mobile Navigation
  if ($('.nav-menu').length) {
    var $mobile_nav = $('.nav-menu').clone().prop({
      class: 'mobile-nav d-lg-none'
    });
    $('body').append($mobile_nav);
    $('body').prepend('<button type="button" class="mobile-nav-toggle d-lg-none"><i class="icofont-navigation-menu"></i></button>');
    $('body').append('<div class="mobile-nav-overly"></div>');

    $(document).on('click', '.mobile-nav-toggle', function(e) {
      $('body').toggleClass('mobile-nav-active');
      $('.mobile-nav-toggle i').toggleClass('icofont-navigation-menu icofont-close');
      $('.mobile-nav-overly').toggle();
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.mobile-nav .drop-down > a', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).next().slideToggle(300);
      $(this).parent().toggleClass('active');
    });

    $(document).click(function(e) {
      var container = $(".mobile-nav, .mobile-nav-toggle");
      if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
        if ($('body').hasClass('mobile-nav-active')) {
          $('body').removeClass('mobile-nav-active');
          $('.mobile-nav-toggle i').toggleClass('icofont-navigation-menu icofont-close');
          $('.mobile-nav-overly').fadeOut();
        }
      }
    });
  } else if ($(".mobile-nav, .mobile-nav-toggle").length) {
    $(".mobile-nav, .mobile-nav-toggle").hide();
  }

  // Navigation active state on scroll
  var nav_sections = $('section');
  var main_nav = $('.nav-menu, #mobile-nav');

  $(window).on('scroll', function() {
    var cur_pos = $(this).scrollTop() + 200;

    nav_sections.each(function() {
      var top = $(this).offset().top,
        bottom = top + $(this).outerHeight();

      if (cur_pos >= top && cur_pos <= bottom) {
        if (cur_pos <= bottom) {
          main_nav.find('li').removeClass('active');
        }
        main_nav.find('a[href="#' + $(this).attr('id') + '"]').parent('li').addClass('active');
      }
      if (cur_pos < 300) {
        $(".nav-menu ul:first li:first").addClass('active');
      }
    });
  });

  // Toggle .header-scrolled class to #header when page is scrolled
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
      $('#header').addClass('header-scrolled');
    } else {
      $('#header').removeClass('header-scrolled');
    }
  });

  if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100) {
    $('#header').addClass('header-scrolled');
  }

  // Back to top button
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
      $('.back-to-top').fadeIn('slow');
    } else {
      $('.back-to-top').fadeOut('slow');
    }
  });

  $('.back-to-top').click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: 0
    }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');
    return false;
  });

  // jQuery counterUp
  $('[data-toggle="counter-up"]').counterUp({
    delay: 10,
    time: 1000
  });

  // Testimonials carousel (uses the Owl Carousel library)
  $(".testimonials-carousel").owlCarousel({
    autoplay: true,
    dots: true,
    loop: true,
    responsive: {
      0: {
        items: 1
      },
      768: {
        items: 2
      },
      900: {
        items: 3
      }
    }
  });

  // Porfolio isotope and filter
  $(window).on('load', function() {
    var portfolioIsotope = $('.portfolio-container').isotope({
      itemSelector: '.portfolio-item'
    });

    $('#portfolio-flters li').on('click', function() {
      $("#portfolio-flters li").removeClass('filter-active');
      $(this).addClass('filter-active');

      portfolioIsotope.isotope({
        filter: $(this).data('filter')
      });
      aos_init();
    });

    // Initiate venobox (lightbox feature used in portofilo)
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.venobox').venobox({
        'share': false
      });
    });
  });

  // Portfolio details carousel
  $(".portfolio-details-carousel").owlCarousel({
    autoplay: true,
    dots: true,
    loop: true,
    items: 1
  });

  // Init AOS
  function aos_init() {
    AOS.init({
      duration: 1000,
      once: true
    });
  }
  $(window).on('load', function() {
    aos_init();
  });

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: `main.js` relies on `jQuery.js`, yet it is referenced in the page before jQuery. Put the `<script>` tag pointing to jQuery.js first in the list of scripts.

Comment: Also, for future reference, please copy and paste code in to the question directly. Images of code aren't very helpful, and take you more time to create.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan sorry for the images, didn't know. The script tag you are mentioning, i don't have it jQuery.js.

Comment: Pic 2, jquery.min.js

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).counterUp is not a function
    at main.js:153:35
    at main.js:219:3
Now, instead of one, shows me two errors.

Comment: I guess you have some code in `main.js` which also relies on `counterup.min.js` make sure that comes first too. In fact, I'd suggest you put all the libraries you need first then your own `main.js` reference.

Comment: Did the owl.carousel.min.js , counterup.min.js and the jquery.min.js before the main, and it doesn't give me any error at least on console, but the dropdown still doesn't work

Comment: well that progress. Now to be able to help you we need to see the code in `main.js`

Comment: Where do you think the error is? @RoryMcCrossan

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to include your jQuery script before your main.js file.

Also please consider in sharing your code here so we can help you better.

Comment: Changing that, now it shows this error Uncaught TypeError: $(...).counterUp is not a function
    at main.js:153:35
    at main.js:219:3

Comment: @EmanuelChaves that's why you should post your javascript code as well. Then we can help. The first change you already did which was to include the jQuery before your main.js file.

Comment: Well, posted it all. Still doesn't work tho. The error doesn't show but the code does not work